# Question lost the duplicate banner for no obvious reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

We have [a question on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14912/does-this-creation-model-conflict-with-modern-science#question) that was closed as a duplicate. But the duplicate banner that should usually appear is not present at all, and the question doesn't even have any reopen votes.

I'm seeing no reason why this question should not have a duplicate banner, something went wrong there.

Comment: You remember what the dupe was? Might be handy to mention it as well. :)

Comment: I'm working on this right now - our historical data is... not the most easily accessed, so I'm fixing properly.  This will also put duplicate information into a question's revision history.

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed, and you can also see the [closure in the revision list](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/posts/14912/revisions), oh yeah!